# How to retrieve content from specific HTML page through Java

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm working in an aplication to parse html content for any website but today, I found the exception for my implemetation.
I'm trying to get content from this url: http://tomfishburne.com/2014/09/socialmedia.html and I get always the following error: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403. I'm using JSOUP library. I tried other 2 options without Jsoup options but that zas not successful. This page is accessible from a browser but not from java. Could you please help with some suggestions?

Thanks

```
    Document doc;
    String url = "http://tomfishburne.com/2014/09/socialmedia.html";
    try {

        Response response = Jsoup
                .connect(url)
                .ignoreContentType(true)
                .userAgent(
                        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                .timeout(12000)
                .followRedirects(true).execute();
        doc = response.parse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .userAgent(
                            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                    .get();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            try {
                URL url2 = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url2
                        .openConnection();
                conn.setRequestProperty(
                        "User-Agent",
                        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36");

                BufferedReader in;
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e2) {
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                //This exception is always thrown because of 403 error code
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to add `ignoreHttpErrors(true)` to your invocation e.g.:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
    .userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0')
    .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
    .get()
```

It turns out that this website always returns 403 Forbidden, even when you access it from the web browser - you can see it in the Firebug for example.

I've created a running Groovy script - https://gist.github.com/wololock/1a002dfaff5d49d14871 It works well.

Comment: Thank you Szymom. I had forgotten this secret method :)